# How to restrict the scope of dynamic HTML CSS in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am displaying dynamic HTML `form` s3 bucket in tabs using Angular 4 component using `innerHTML` element. The issue is that HTML file has some CSS links. That CSS file is affecting the already existing `header` component. How to restrict that to only tab?

Comment: my question is that css is not in our control dynamic html has the css links .and we dont want to change that css  thanks for replay

Comment: CSS is all about your selectors, if you are having conflict you just need to be more specific.  If you want the CSS to be applied to a specific element call that specific element out.  You can use an ID tag, create a specific class and add the class dynamically on creation, you can do one of a million things here.  It's all about being as specific as possible with your selector. Try this tutorial it should help you with this. http://flukeout.github.io/